# Is the implicit client security is fragile or my concerns is not valid

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am using the implicit client in the identity server, in the other hand there is a native android app,

My security concerns is:

1- **App reverse engineering:** if the attacker get access to the `client_Id`

, `redirect_uri` and/or `response_type`, he will be able to mimic the login request.

by doing this he is impersonating the original client

2- **Man in the middle**: those `client_id`,... is send to the identity server through the https URI which is not encrypted, why not hiding them in the Header?

3- Browser will resend the token in the URI revealing it to the man in the middle if the redirect URI is not `oob` or `localhost`, the browser default behavior is redirecting to the Location, so can we force the developers when they register a client to use oob,

You can say ohh no the app is reading the token and close the browser so fast, before the browser sends the request,

Can we really rely on the app speed of closing the browser, this is sounds squishy?

Which question is legitimate concerns and which is not, also how to solve the legitimate concerns.

About point 1: how google is protecting it's services like google Map, the client Quote is vital and it has to be very secure, Right  !!?

**Edit**

if we pass the client_id in the header to encrypt it, we will violate the http 1.1 spec and oauth2 spec, still we didn't do much, because the client_id is reside inside the handset, by small reverse engineering you can get it

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding point number 3:**
The token response after a successful authentication will be something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://example.com/cb#access_token=2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA
          &state=xyz&token_type=example&expires_in=3600
```

The user-agent will redirect to the URL provided in the location parameter. Here there is no need to worry about MiTM attacks because the access-token is included in the *URL hash fragment* & hash fragments are not sent in the HTTP request messages, in other words the hash fragment will not leave the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but the token service will only return the user to the pre-registered callback uri for the client.

2 & 3. You should use HTTPS for most everything on the web these days.

Comment: My point is idsr is not using the encryption even if you use https .. By sending the parameters throw the uri you are not encriping those parameters .. By parameters here I mean client id, redirect uri and response type

Comment: 1. Even though the authorization server will return the client to the registered `redirect_uri` that might not be enough. Given that an attacker knows the client_id & the redirect_uri he can still issue tokens as if he is the legit client by intercepting the redirect response, enumerate it & extract the `location` header value which contains the token. This can be easily done with a native client (desktop/mobile).

Comment: Yes, by using https that doesn't mean that the uri is encrypted , if any one mimic the request and send it again he will get the token

Comment: You seem to think the URI is not encrypted when using HTTPS -- it it.

Comment: ohhh, ok, but how about the reverse engineering?